# use Google map with php and mysql to display locations

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps-api-3, inner-join, latitude-longitude

i have a map page that include a Google map  to display  users static  locations using the php and mysql  because the **longitude and lattitude** are stored in the database in **village table**  but the **village id** is in the a foreign key in the user table so i used the **INNER join**
but the problem is that the browser do not show anything  can  anyone help me ???

## map.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php print "$firstname $lastname"; ?></title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link href="default_ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script>

<style type="text/css">
            #map {
    width: 850px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 76px;
    left: 253px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC9YBiNmZG9jIWY32FzJwn92iuJtJZHjfc&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
                       new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                       new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
            var center = null;
            var map = null;
            var currentPopup;
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
                var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                bounds.extend(pt);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pt,
                    icon: icon,
                    map: map
                });
                var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: info,
                    maxWidth: 300
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                    if (currentPopup != null) {
                        currentPopup.close();
                        currentPopup = null;
                    }
                    popup.open(map, marker);
                    currentPopup = popup;
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
                    map.panTo(center);
                    currentPopup = null;
                });
            }           
            function initMap() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                    zoom: 14,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
                    },
                    navigationControl: true,
                    navigationControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN
                    }
                });


<?php

$query = mysql_query("SELECT lattitude, longiude FROM user u 
                      INER JOIN village v
                       ON u.village = v.id")or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
 // $name = $row['user_name'];
  $lat = $row['lattitude'];
  $lon = $row['longitude'];
  //$desc = $row['desc'];
//'<b>$name</b>


  echo("addMarker($lat, $lon <br />');\n");

}

?>
 center = bounds.getCenter();
     map.fitBounds(bounds);

     }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
<?php  /*require_once('header.php');*/ ?>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="page-wrapper">
      <div id="page">
            <div id="wide-content">
              <div id="map"></div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <?php /*require_once('footer.php');*/ ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

## databse stucture

village table:

- id
- village_name
- district_id
- lattitude
- longitude

user table:

- user_id
- first_name
- last_name
- governorate
- district
- village
- birth_date
- email_address
- specialization
- user_name
- password
- interest
- registered_date
- last_log_date

Comment: What does your final HTML look like?  Is the addMarker stuff added?  Also, are you sure your field is lattitude? Perhaps it should be latitude. And the same for longitude.

Comment: it does not show anything even the google map is not displayed  and the name fields are correct

Comment: Not according to your code. Your SQL says longiude.

Answer (score 0):

The `<br />` in addMarker() function is causing the problem it and the `(`& `)` are redundant.

```
echo("addMarker($lat, $lon <br />');\n");
```

Try

```
echo "addMarker($lat, $lon);\n";
```